# Get the current version of the package in GO

Tags: go

I am building a library and I need to check at runtime which version the user is using, for example to pass the version to a User agent etc...
Is there a way to do that in go?

Comment: Which version of what?

Comment: The version of the library

Comment: If you're building the library, then you can do whatever you want, i.e. use a "Version" variable or function.

Comment: But that will include changing the version variable every time i publish a new version

Comment: You need to change the version _somewhere_, do you mean you want to set a variable at build time rather than in the source?

Comment: Yes something like that if possible